# How to close boost asio server socket with all client sockets connected

Tags: c++, boost-asio, serversocket

I use [boost:asio::ip::tcp::acceptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/acceptor.html) to create server socket in my app. I close this acceptor socket using `close` function, than `stop` function in `io_service` but all connected client sockets closes only when my app is closed. How can i fix that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Do either of the following:

- invoke [`socket::close()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/close/overload1.html) on the sockets.
- destroy the socket.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716271/1053968) answer for details on how the socket will be closed during destruction.

[`io_service::stop()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html) only stops processing of the event loop.  Work can still be posted into the `io_service`, and existing work will remain in the `io_service`.   Thus, the application must call `socket::close()` on each of the sockets it wishes to close.  For a portable graceful closure, call [`socket::shutdown()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/shutdown/overload1.html) before calling `close()`.

It may be worth taking the time to review Boost.Asio's [HTTP Server 1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html) example.  It uses a [`connection_manager`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server/connection_manager.hpp) to shutdown all connections.

Comment: I am exactly looking at this HTTP Server 1 example...
My question is that it closes the sockets perfectly fine. But, isn;t anything required to be done at the client side ? As in there is a socket object corresponding to a client also... Do we not have to close that socket also  ?

Comment: I have posted this query in the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267854/asio-client-server-shutdown

You might want to have a look at that question as well for more details.. Thanks in advance ...