# Do boost asio sockets have proper RAII cleanup

Tags: c++, boost-asio, raii

I tried looking through source but I cant navigate that much of a template code. 
Basically: this is what documentation says (for `close()`):

> ```
> Remarks    
> For portable behaviour with respect to graceful 
> closure  of a connected socket, call shutdown() before closing the socket.
> ```

I can do that manually, but if possible it would be nice to rely on RAII.

So if I have socket going out of scope do I need to call `shutdown()` and `close()` on it, or it will be done automatically?

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the socket in a class that calls close/shutdown in the dtor?

Comment: A simple wrapper (similar as the usual lock guard implementations etc. pp.) would do? From your cite it seems for me they don't do this automatically on destruction of the socket.

Comment: @Luther Same idea at same time ;), looks like being a solution ...

Comment: looks like socket_holder does this, but I did not manage to find docs for it, comments in source say : namespace boost {
namespace asio {
namespace detail {

// Implement the resource acquisition is initialisation idiom for sockets.
class socket_holder
  : private noncopyable
{
public:
  // Construct as an uninitialised socket.
  socket_holder()
    : socket_(invalid_socket)

Comment: and in dtor:   ~socket_holder()
  {
    if (socket_ != invalid_socket)
    {
      boost::system::error_code ec;
      socket_ops::state_type state = 0;
      socket_ops::close(socket_, state, true, ec);
    }
  }

Comment: Is this not Boost's equivalent to `shutdown`? (See `man 2 shutdown`) It gracefully closes, say, a TCP connection and causes the other side to get an EOF. (As opposed to a "Connection reset by peer.") `close` will release the socket regardless, and the resources will get freed, but one will transmit a clean close on the network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can rely on the socket performing proper cleanup with RAII.

When an IO object, such as socket, is destroyed, its [destructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object/_basic_io_object.html) will invoke `destroy()` on the IO object's service, passing in an instance of the `implementation_type` on which the IO object's service will operate.  The [`SocketService`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SocketService.html) requirements state that `destroy()` will implicitly cancel asynchronous operations *as-if* by calling the `close()` on the service, which has a post condition that `is_open()` returns false.  Furthermore, the service's `close()` will cause outstanding asynchronous operations to complete as soon as possible.  Handlers for cancelled operations will be passed the error code `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`, and scheduled for deferred invocation within the `io_service`.  These handlers are removed from the `io_service` if they are either invoked from a thread processing the event loop or the `io_service` is [destroyed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/_io_service.html).

Comment: i will need 2 hours to understand the A, but seems legit... :)

Comment: so that means if two sockets share io_service one exiting out of scope will affect other?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl No.  The the IO object's `io_service`, returned from [`get_io_service()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/get_io_service.html), is different from the IO object's service, returned from [`get_service()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/get_service/overload1.html).  While sockets may both use the same `io_service`, each socket will have its own `SocketService`.