# Permission refused when connecting to domain socket created by Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost-asio, socat

I'm trying to create a server that receives connections via domain sockets. I can start the server and I can see the socket being created on the filesystem. But whenever I try to connect to it via [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) I get the following error:

`2015/03/02 14:00:10 socat[62720] E connect(3, LEN=19 AF=1 "/var/tmp/rpc.sock", 19): Connection refused`

This is my Asio code (only the .cpp files). Despite the post title I'm using the Boost-free version of Asio but I don't think that would be a problem.

```
namespace myapp {

  DomainListener::DomainListener(const string& addr) : socket{this->service}, Listener{addr} {
    remove(this->address.c_str());
    stream_protocol::endpoint ep(this->address);
    stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor(this->service, ep);
    acceptor.async_accept(this->socket, ep, bind(&DomainListener::accept_callback, this, _1));
  }

  DomainListener::~DomainListener() {
    this->service.stop();
    remove(this->address.c_str());
  }

  void DomainListener::accept_callback(const error_code& ec) noexcept {
    this->socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(this->data), bind(&DomainListener::read_data, this, _1, _2));
  }

  void DomainListener::read_data(const error_code& ec, size_t length) noexcept {
    //std::cerr << "AAA" << std::endl;
    //std::cerr << this->data[0] << std::endl;
    //std::cerr << "BBB" << std::endl;
  }

} 



Listener::Listener(const string& addr) : work{asio::io_service::work(this->service)} {
    this->address = addr;
  }

  void Listener::listen() {
    this->service.run();
  }

  Listener::~Listener() {
  }
```

In the code that uses these classes I call `listen()` whenever I want to start listening to the socket for connections.

I've managed to get this to work with libuv and changed to Asio because I thought it would make for more readable code but I'm finding the documentation to be very ambiguous.

Comment: Check the permissions of the socket file, in particular check that the `socat` user can read and write to it.

Comment: All processes are under my username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is most likely the lifetime of the `acceptor`.

The `acceptor` is an automatic variable in the `DomainListener` constructor.  When the `DomainListener` constructor completes, the `acceptor` is destroyed, causing the acceptor to close and cancel outstanding operations, such as the `async_accept` operations.  Cancelled operations will be provided an error code of `asio::error::operation_aborted` and scheduled for deferred invocation within the `io_service`.  Hence, there may not be an active listener when attempting to connect to the domain socket.  For more details on the affects of IO object destruction, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716271/1053968) answer.

```cpp
DomainListener::DomainListener(const string&) : /* ... */
{
  // ...
  stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor(...);
  acceptor.async_accept(..., bind(accept_callback, ...));
} // acceptor destroyed, and accept_callback likely cancelled
```

To resolve this, consider extending the lifetime of the `acceptor` by making it a data member for `DomainListener`.  Additionally, checking the `error_code` provided to asynchronous operations can provide more insight into the asynchronous call chains.

---

Here is a complete minimal example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06dc9862d13760b0) using domain sockets with Asio.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

/// @brief server demonstrates using domain sockets to accept
///        and read from a connection.
class server
{
public:
  server(
    boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
    const std::string& file)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service_, 
        boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::endpoint(file)),
      client_(io_service_)
  {
    std::cout << "start accepting connection" << std::endl;
    acceptor_.async_accept(client_,
      boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

private:

  void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    std::cout << "handle_accept: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    if (error) return;

    std::cout << "start reading" << std::endl;
    client_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
      boost::bind(&server::handle_read, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_read(
    const boost::system::error_code& error,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    std::cout << "handle_read: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    if (error) return;

    std::cout << "read: ";
    std::cout.write(buffer_.begin(), bytes_transferred);
    std::cout.flush();
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor_;
  boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::socket client_;
  std::array<char, 1024> buffer_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    std::cerr << "Usage: <file>\n";
    return 1;
  }

  // Remove file on startup and exit.
  std::string file(argv[1]);
  struct file_remover
  {
    file_remover(std::string file): file_(file) { std::remove(file.c_str()); }
    ~file_remover() { std::remove(file_.c_str()); }
    std::string file_;
  } remover(file);

  // Create and run the server.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  server s(io_service, file);
  io_service.run();
}
```

Coliru does not have socat installed, so the following commands use OpenBSD netcat to write "asio domain socket example" to the domain socket:

```bash
export SOCKFILE=$PWD/example.sock
./a.out $SOCKFILE &
sleep 1
echo "asio domain socket example" | nc -U $SOCKFILE
```

Which outputs:

```
start accepting connection
handle_accept: Success
start reading
handle_read: Success
read: asio domain socket example
```

Comment: Jesus, I could kiss you. I was seriously considering going back to the callback hell of libuv.

Comment: What is `std::remove(const char *)` and why don't you need to include anything for that?

Comment: @Florian [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) is used to delete a file and is from the included `cstdio` header.  The overloads in the `algorithm` header provide a very different functionality.