# ASIO client server shutdown

Tags: sockets, boost, boost-asio

Please refer to the ASIO examples at : 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html

The connection class code is at : 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server/connection.cpp

This class has a stop() function which calls stop on socket that has been created corresponding to a connection request to server (from void server::start_accept())

The client code resides at :
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/client/sync_client.cpp

This class also creates a socket at the client end, but this code does not close the socket.

My question is that there are 2 sockets that are opened: from client to server and vice-a-versa

So, I have 2 questions :

a) Is just closing the socket which the server has opened sufficient or should we also call close on the socket inside the client code ?

b) Should we call shutdown on socket before calling close ?

Comment: @sehe  : Any comments ?

Comment: @rafix07 : Any comments ?